# Programa en Java no conecta correctamente con MySQL en Ubuntu

Tags: java, mysql, ubuntu

Tengo un problema con mi programa en java , porque mi programa como que no encuentra la bd .

esta es mi clase conectar aqui esta todo bien porque sis se conecta con My sql pero cuando hago una consulta solo me tira el mensaje no se puedo actalizar que tengo cuando tira un error.

```
package contabilidad_sgc;

import java.sql.Connection;
import com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class conectar {

     Connection conn=null;
     String bd="sistema_contabilidad";
     String login="root";
     String password="root";
     String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/sistema_contabilidad_sgc";

     public Connection conexion(){
        try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,login,password);
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e){

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se pudo establecer la conexión con la base de datos "+bd);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(conectar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(conectar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(conectar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

clase cliente la cual hace la consulta:

```
package contabilidad_sgc;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author Jeredick Escobar
 */
public class cliente extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    conectar cn = new conectar();
    Connection cc = cn.conexion();
    JTable table;
    DefaultTableModel dfm = new DefaultTableModel();
    public cliente() {
        initComponents();

        table = this.jTable1;
        table.setModel(dfm);
        dfm.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[]{"ID","NIT","NOMBRE","DIRECCION","E-MAIL","TELEFONO","MOVIL"});
        try{
            Statement st = cc.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM CLIENTE");

            while(rs.next()){
                dfm.addRow(new Object[]{rs.getInt("ID"),rs.getString("NIT"), rs.getString("NOMBRE"),rs.getString("DIRECCION1"),rs.getString("DIRECCION2"),rs.getInt("TELEFONO1"),rs.getInt("TELEFONO2")});
            }
            dfm.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                if(e.getType()==TableModelEvent.UPDATE){
                int columna = e.getColumn();
                int fila = e.getFirstRow();
                if(columna==1){
                    String sql = "UPDATE CLIENTE SET NIT = '"+jTable1.getValueAt(fila, columna)+"' WHERE ID ="+jTable1.getValueAt(fila, 0);
                    actualizar_data(sql);
                }
                }
            }
            });  
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se pudo actualizar");
        }
    }
    void actualizar_data(String act){
            try{
                PreparedStatement ps = cc.prepareStatement(act);
                ps.execute();

            }
            catch(SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se pudo actualizar");
            }
    }
```

gracias por su ayuda

Comment: En los catch que muestra el mensaje que no se pudo actualizar (ej. catch(SQLException e)) o imprime la traza de la excepción por consola (e.printStackTrace()) o envíala a algún log para que puedas ver el error que está ocurriendo y lo puedas compartir con nosotros, y poder ayudarte.

Comment: Gracias si me funciono imprimir el log

Comment: Entonces lo resolviste??

Comment: Si lo pude resolver , el error era que en el statement puse el nombre de la tabla en mayúsculas y en la bd estaba en minusculas

Answer (score 0):

Deberías checar el nombre de la base de datos porque noto que tienes una variable que se llama bd y le tienes asignado como `sistema_contabilidad`, mientras que en la url tienes:

```
String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/sistema_contabilidad_sgc";
```

tienes diferentes nombres en `bd` y la `url` de base de datos.

También deberías checar la clase, porque tienes:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

Y he visto que es:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

Sin el `cj`.

Comment: La variable no la utilizo , y ya revise el nombre y si es el mismo y ya le quite el cj a la clase pero sigue sin funcionar